# Longtable paragraph cells doesn't wrap properly

Tags: longtable, booktabs, wrap

I'm creating a table with the following packages

- `longtable` for tables with lots of rows
- `booktabs` for pretty book styled tables
- `xcolor` with `[table]` option to add zebra style colors

However text in cells doesn't wrap properly as specified, see below code sample

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,204,204}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{myblue!15}

\begin{document}

{
%\small

\begin{longtable}[l]{p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.6\textwidth}|p{0.15\textwidth}}
\caption{Primer list for IRD-associated loci long-range PCRs}
\label{tab:ch3_1_LR_primers}\\
\toprule
%\rowcolor{gray!20}\textbf{Text 1} & \textbf{Text sequence} & \textbf{Number}\\
\textbf{Text1} & \textbf{Text Sequences} & \textbf{Number} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption{continued from previous page} \\
\endhead
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAextralongtextsshallbewrppeasdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffd & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBasdffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx & 67.05\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

On clicking typeset I get this:
[image]

Could you help on how to wrap the text in cells properly?

Comment: The example "words" you selected in order to show that the hyphenation does not work as you expect are not really words, so the usual hyphenation rules can't be applied in a sensible way. Does your real table contain actual words or just strings of characters? For the latter case, you may want to take a look at the `seqsplit` package.

Comment: this is unrelated to longtable, you are trying to hyphenate BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBasdffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff using the English hyphenation tables and they do not match so you would see the same thing in top level paragraphs in the document with no tables or packages loaded.

Comment: I have another complex table generated by sphinx template, some of the cells are wrapped so I created this dummy one. Anyway your answer enlighten me of the word split behavior, I was thinking there can be hyphens between them. 

Thanks @leandriis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your real words are long as shoed letters sequences, that can help `seqsplit` package as already mentioned @lendriss in his comment. Using it with combination of the `tabularray package gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}  %, varwidth
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,204,204}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Primer list for IRD-associated loci long-range PCRs},
  label = {tab:ch3_1_LR_primers}
                    ]{vline{2-Y} = {solid},
                      colspec = {l X[j, cmd=\seqsplit] % enable split any to long sequence in column
                                   Q[c, si={table-format=2.2}]},
%                      measure = vbox,
                       row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c},
                     row{even} = {bg=myblue!15}, 
                      rowhead = 1}
    \toprule
Text1       &   Text Sequences              & {{{Number}}}  \\
    \midrule
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAextralongtextsshallbewrppeasdfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffd
                                            & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA           & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA         & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBasdffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff 
                                            & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.87\\
ABC\_02\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.23\\
ABC\_02\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.91\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 67.05\\
ABC\_01\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 67.01\\
ABC\_01\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB   & 66.87\\
ABC\_03\_A & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   & 66.98\\
ABC\_03\_B & BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                                            & 67.05\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```